# Публикация проекта на github

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

Занимаясь изучением react я подумал, что было бы хорошо созданный проект залить на github и настроить там pages. Однако при работе я использовал не react api, а работал из nodejs, использовал сторонние библиотеки, создал структуру папок и файлов. На сколько я понимаю есть функция build, которая компонует созданный проект и по логике я могу запустить проект из сборки где угодно. Возможно, я в чем-то ошибаюсь и хочу чтобы кто-то объяснил мне это.

Пока что у меня есть пара вопросов:

1. Возможно ли разместить такой проект или нужно использовать именно api react-а?
2. Если использовать api, то не получится ли так, что код придётся размещать в одном файле?
3. Как тогда правильнее размещать такие проекты на github? (именно для демонстрации того, что проект использует определённые технологии)
4. Не будет ли проблем с CORS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub Pages - это по сути front-end хостинг. В проекте он будет открывать index.html, в котором уже подгружаются **собранные** стили, скрипты и т.д.

1. *Возможно ли разместить такой проект или нужно использовать именно api react-а?*

- **На чем проект был написал изначально - не важно. Нужно просто его собрать.**

2. *Если использовать api, то не получится ли так, что код придётся размещать в одном файле?*

- **После сборки код и так будет в одном файле**.

3. *Как тогда правильнее размещать такие проекты на github? (именно для демонстрации того, что проект использует определённые технологии)*

- **Настроить сборщик (webpack, например). На выходе должен быть index.html и файлы со скриптами и стилями**

4. *Не будет ли проблем с CORS?*

- **Нет, это сюда не относится**

---

Пример структуры проекта:

```
/src -- Исходный код проекта
   /index.jsx
   /components/
   /...
/dist -- Собранный код проекта
   /bundle.js
   /bundle.css
/index.html
/package.json
/...
```